# Brooks' Theorem Time complexity

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, coloring, graph-connectivity

I am looking to derive an algorithm that finds,  *for every connected graph $G$ that is neither complete nor an odd cycle, a $\Delta(G)$-colouring in time $O(m+n)$.*

When we proved Brooks' theorem we used the depth first search (DFS) algorithm which will be helpful to prove this but I am not quite sure how to proceed with this problem.

Any tip or material about time complexity of Brooks' theorem would be much appreciated

Comment: The proof of Brooks' theorem you saw should directly translate to an algorithm; just go through it carefully and make sure that you can make every step run in $O(m+n)$ time. (Whenever you break things down into cases, the algorithm should determine the case you're in for a particular $G$. Whenever you say "there exists a vertex $v$..." the algorithm should find $v$. And so on.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I really appreciate it. But is there any reference you know that gives me more information on this problem?